# How to setup a callback on all methods and properties with moq

Tags: c#, moq

Is there a way to set a callback to all the members without having to set them each individually?

I am trying to verify that all memebrs get called from the current thread, so I would like to do something like this, but there is no SetupAll().

```
var mockMyType = new Mock<IMyType>();
var expectedThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
mockMyType.SetupAll().Callback(() => Assert.AreEqual(expectedThread, Thread.CurrentThread));
```

Answer (score 1):

I find it hard to understand the question.

If you really need to setup all properties and methods, don't you need to provide return variables, etc let alone parameter expectations?

But if you need to only set it up to complain if it is called, without setup, itwill be by behaviour passed to the constructors (make it strict). Alternatively, if you want to make it ignore calls not setup, construct it as you have, with no parameter.

Comment: I want all properties and methods to have the default non-strict behavior, except I want to throw an exception if any property or method is used from a different thread.

Comment: Wow, that is a complex requirement - this will lead to brittle test. **Re-design your classes for testability** removing the requirement for cross-thread-behaviour.

Comment: Agreed with @Aliostad. What's the use case for requiring methods to be only run on a certain thread?

Comment: I am taking an existing library that is not thread safe, and adding async methods to it and making it thread safe. I am doing this by adding a layer on top of the interface that will queue the requests and run them all sequentially on a single thread.

Comment: Yes. So I am using dependency injection to give the new class (the shim) the the interface to the old one. Then in the unit test I want to mock those interfaces and make sure they are called from a single thread.

Comment: My suggestion is to remove most of the actual work and put to a class requiring no threading and only test that class. Then have one class which spawns the threads and stuff and uses the other one and write no test for it... my work is heavily multi-threaded and that is what I am doing